# Nginx ingress use regular expression in hosts

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I have different DNS names which pointed to one IP of the ingress controller (1.2.3.4) of k8s cluster.

for example:

```
client1-app1.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4
client1-app2.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4

client2-app1.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4
client2-app2.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4
```

I have a Nginx Ingress Controller. And I need to achieve the next logic

```
*-app1.domain.com -> service1
*-app2.domain.com -> service2
```

For theoretic Nginx ingress config, it will look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - "*.domain.com"
    secretName: my-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: '*-app1.domain.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path_app1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: '*-app2.domain.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path_app2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2
            port:
              number: 80
```

But this config will not work, because of:

> spec.rules[1].host: Invalid value: "*-app1.domain.com": a wildcard
> DNS-1123 subdomain must start with '*.', followed by a valid DNS
> subdomain, which must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters,
> '-' or '.' and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g.
> '*.example.com', regex used for validation is
> '*.a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)*')

So, is it possible to achieve somehow this logic on Nginx Ingress?

Comment: not find an elegant solution in Nginx Ingress - and start to use Traefik with CRD IngressRoute for this logic